# Magento 2 - Hide/Show custom EAV attribute after if condition

Tags: magento2, entity-attribute-value

I created a new EAV attribute using this code :

```
'information',
    [
        'type' => 'int',
        'default' => null,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => false
    ]
```

this attribute is by default hidden, but I want to visible it after a condition, is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the attribute is set per global or store view, so this should not be possible. However, when you display your attribute, for example on your product view page, you can build in some logic to decide wether it should be displayed or not.

**Solution 1**

Here's an example I used in a similar way in phtml on product view:

```
<?php 
    $product = $block->getProduct();
    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);
    if('>>your_condition_here<<'){
        echo $_attribute;
    } 
?>
```

You could use this anywhere you want, especially outside of the details tab.

**Solution 2**

Another way would be to extend the default detail tab and build in your condition. Copy vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php to your module or theme and extend the first if condition (line 83)* in `getAddtionalData()` to your needs.

Change

```
if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr))
```

To

```
if (($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() || ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'information' && '>>>your condition here <<<')) && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr))
```

*I should add that this works for M2 2.2.x. I don't know about 2.3